# Как избежать дубли в определённом столбце загружаемой таблицы?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
BULK INSERT [dbLEGO].[dbo].[F]
FROM 'D:\ucheba\DB\lr1\DataGenerate\out\Fact.txt'
WITH (CODEPAGE = 'ACP', DATAFILETYPE = 'char', FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
GO
```

Как мне избежать дубли в определённом столбце загружаемой таблицы?
(Можно ли как-то вставить в эту конструкцию join?)

Answer (score 4):

> Можно ли как-то вставить в эту конструкцию join?

Нельзя.

> Как мне избежать дубли в определённом столбце загружаемой таблицы?

По завершении импорта отдельным запросом удалить дубликаты.

Answer (score 1):

Запретить дубли в определенном столбце можно, создав уникальный индекс, только вставка завалится с ошибкой.

Ещё один момент: если в столбце значение, которое уже есть в таблице, то чего вы хотите в итоге? Вставить строку, а это значение оставить пустым, или отбросить строку?

В любом случае универсальный метод: вставляйте в промежуточную (можно временную) таблицу, а потом крутите данные и обрабатывайте дубликаты по любой необходимой логике